# SSRS Reporting service authentication detail save

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012, ssrs-2012, business-intelligence

I am having SSRS report under developed BIDS-2012. I have successfully deployed the project on server and having access rights to the SSRS Portal in web browser.

When I open any report every time it asks me for LoginId/Password as shown in below!

[image]

Going back from browser and return to same report also ask me for LoginId/Password again.

So is there any way to set this Id/Password (not in browser cookies) that It will not ask me for assigned user/Group for next login details??
Or Credentials could be saved on Report server??

**Edited**:
I am getting this property of Data_Source and getting below Wizard.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked the data source that is stored on the SSRS Portal? Click to Manage the data source, go to its properties and look at the Connection and Credentials section.

You probably have 'By prompting the user viewing the report for credentials' selected.
If you change it to use specific credentials stored on the server, or use the credentials of the user viewing the report (depending on your situation) the user will not be prompted each time.

Which option you choose will depend on how you want to secure the underlying database the reports run from.

The first option (Windows authentication) doesn't prompt the user, but relies on you setting up security on your database so that all users can access it with their Windows logins, either for each user, or for a Windows group. Some databases are set up like this, and that's fine.

The second option (use a specific username and password) is for when you don't want the user to be prompted, and in effect you're making the reports server the user: you set up a SQL Server username and password and give it permissions to the database- and then the SSRS server logs on with the username and password you supply for the data source. The user does not get prompted, and for security you make sure that only authorised people can get to the report portal itself.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I am trying as you suggested and getting above (Edited question) Wizard for saving password. So what are the different uses of different options? And which is for my requirement? I think second one should work for me but I can not execute this report to my local (don't ask why), so what credentials should i give in that, "Database server" or "System Login user"??

Comment: Have edited answer to give more information on the two options.

Comment: Thanks Rich! thanks a lot for your explanation. And second option worked for my requirement!! :)